# Models and databases in EF

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, entity-framework, model

I have two SQL Server databases (`dbInfo` and `dbData`) and I want to add an/two EF model/s to my .NET application (WPF, ASP.NET MVC, ...).

**Q:** What is the best approach when adding the EF model; add two models, one for each database ?

- add two edmx models, one for each database ?
- add one edmx model with the two databases using [SQL Synonyms](http://rachel53461.wordpress.com/2011/05/22/tricking-ef-to-span-multiple-databases/) ?
- other version...

Comment: The biggest problem I found so far is that you are limited to whatever the limitations are of your Synonyms. This may or may not be a problem for you depending on how your servers are setup and what sort of queries you have. For example, you can't use the `OUTPUT` keyword over a linked server, so if your synonym pointed to a procedure on a linked server that used `OUTPUT`, this would cause an error.

Answer (score 0):

That largely depends on the amount of interaction between the two databases.

Nevertheless, I would strongly prefer to keep them in separate models. One model accommodating two databases introduces a lot of intricacies and dependencies that you'd rather avoid:

- The synonyms must be defined.
- You may have to revise the synonyms in the main database when the "other" database changes.
- You must update to whole model if one database changes.
- The databases (probably) can't have a different versions (an edmx model is version-sensitive).
- A synonym is a path to an object in a different database. The path can be broken by moving one of the databases, or by renaming the target object. You only notice at run time.
- Backup/restore must be in sync.

And probably more...

However, there could be one compelling demand that blows away these objections. If you want modify data in both databases in one transaction it is much easier to work with synonyms and one context (and one database connection). Otherwise you'll have to use `TransactionScope` in your code and have DTC enabled on the database server.